# parsing and showing the information extracted from json returned from google map place api

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I am new to android.so cooperate with me.

I need to parse the json response comes from the google map api and show the nearby resturants list only from USA .

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking at the android json documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

Comment: thanks for reply i want to know something that can i look at the result in json given by this link by any means because i don't know the attributes  (***https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=resturants&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAiFpFd85eMtfbvmVNEYuNds5TEF9FjIPI***)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

check http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html for API details.

Comment: thanks for reply i want to know something that can i look at the result in json given by this link by any means because i don't know the attributes  (***https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=resturants&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAiFpFd85eMtfbvmVNEYuNds5TEF9FjIPI***)