# JSON parsing error google map place api

Tags: android, json, google-maps

Hello again this is my second question in SO. This is my first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009163/parsing-and-showing-the-information-extracted-from-json-returned-from-google-map). The answer given by the guys are really helpful so i tried to implements it.And here is my implementation..

Making a JSONFunction class with a static method whcch will return the json ***Object***.

```
public class JSONFunction {

public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

  //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    try{

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);            
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
}
```

NOW MY MAIN ACTIVITY is..

```
public class JsonExampleActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
JSONFunction JSONfunction;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    JSONObject json = JSONFunction.getJSONfromURL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1000&types=resturants&sensor=false&key=0bBgLl42nWwl7TQHrAFpY89v2FeLlijIGTLJ1AA");

    try{
        JSONObject httpattributr= json.getJSONObject("html_attributions");
        //JSONObject results =new JSONObject("results");
        JSONArray  JArray = httpattributr.getJSONArray("results");

        for(int i=0;i<JArray.length();i++){                     
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            JSONObject e = JArray.getJSONObject(i);
            map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("name", "" + e.getString("name"));
            map.put("type", "type: " +  e.getString("type"));
            mylist.add(map);            
        }       
    }catch(JSONException e)        {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                    new String[] { "name", "type" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
            Toast.makeText(JsonExampleActivity.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        }
    });
}
}
```

But i am getting error in logcat as

```
11-04 19:56:53.099: ERROR/log_tag(298): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["html_attributions"] is not a JSONObject.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance.

The JSON result is look like

```
  {
"html_attributions" : [
"Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.yellowpages.com.au/\"\u003eYellow Pages\u003c/a\u003e"
  ],
 "results" : [
{
  "geometry" : {
    "location" : {
      "lat" : -33.8719830,
      "lng" : 151.1990860
    }
  },
    "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    "id" : "677679492a58049a7eae079e0890897eb953d79b",
    "name" : "Zaaffran Restaurant - BBQ and GRILL, Darling Harbour",
    "rating" : 3.90,
    "reference" : "CpQBjAAAAHDHuimUQATR6gfoWNmZlk5dKUKq_n46BpSzPQCjk1m9glTKkiAHH_Gs4xGttdOSj35WJJDAV90dAPnNnZK2OaxMgogdeHKQhIedh6UduFrW53wtwXigUfpAzsCgIzYNI0UQtCj38cr_DE56RH4Wi9d2bWbbIuRyDX6tx2Fmk2EQzO_lVJ-oq4ZY5uI6I75RnxIQJ6smWUVVIHup9Jvc517DKhoUidfNPyQZZIgGiXS_SwGQ1wg0gtc",
    "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
    "vicinity" : "Harbourside Centre 10 Darling Drive, Darling Harbour, Sydney"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
JSONObject httpattributr= json.getJSONObject("html_attributions");
JSONArray  JArray = httpattributr.getJSONArray("results");
```

to

```
JSONArray httpattributr= json.getJSONArray("html_attributions");
JSONArray  JArray = json.getJSONArray("results");
```

EDIT: The result array isn't a child of or element in the html_attributions array - they are siblings.

Answer (score 1):

"html_attributions" key has JSONArray as it's value, so instead of

```
JSONObject httpattributr= json.getJSONObject("html_attributions");
```

try using...

```
JSONArray httpattributtr = json.getJSONArray("html_attributions");
```

Comment: Actually JSONFunction reurn a JSONOject so how can i convert JSONObject to JSONArray and soory for my mistake i edited it.

Answer (score 0):

In the json that you're parsing, there must not be a key named "html_attributions". What does your json look like?

Comment: Hey Kurtis i posted the json format.and here is the link http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchResponses